# How to display groupID (GID) correctly in C?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm trying to display my userID and groupID through one of my functions in my C program. The userID is displaying correctly (501) but my groupID isn't. When I check my groupID using the command "id -g" I get 20 but when I run it through my program using my function I get the value 1.

This is my code.

```
int Registerpw(char **args){

    register struct passwd *pw;
    register uid_t uid;
    int c;
    register gid_t gid;
    register struct group *grp;
    grp = getgrgid(gid);

    uid = geteuid();
    pw = getpwuid(uid);


    if (pw)
    {
            printf("%d,",uid);      // userID
            printf("%d,", gid);    //groupID
            puts (pw->pw_name);
            puts(grp->gr_name);


    }
    else{
        printf("failed\n");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

My output is

```
501,1,USERNAME
daemon
```

Comment: Are you missing a statement that assigns a value to `gid`?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `register gid_t gid` is getting the gid

Comment: @Recap That line of code merely declared & defined the variable of `gid`, leaving the value uninitialized. The code above never initialized `gid`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code merely declared & defined the variable of `gid`, but left its value uninitialized. You shall assign a correct value to it:

```
register gid_t gid;
gid = getgid();
```

Or simply:

```
register gid_t gid = getgid();
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That was a silly mistake by me.

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to print all of that in one line? If you look at my output you can see that it print the groupName on the line below because I have it in a "puts". Do you know how i can avoid using it in a "puts" and maybe print it a different way?

Comment: @Recap `puts` would append a newline character to the string you try to print. If you don't want the newline character, you could use something like `printf("%s", pw->pw_name);` instead.

Comment: When I change it to `printf("%s", pw->pw_name);`  I get `"Segmentation fault: 11"`  returned and it exits the program

Comment: @Recap Could you please post another question describing the issue (recommended)? Or please at least edit your original question to add your current code which causes the issue (not recommended). Since you may have had multiple changes to your code and others won't know what's really happening.

Comment: Sorry that was my error. I have it working perfectly now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**i just simply declare variables using int datatype,and use getgid() and geteuid() method to display userid and groupid.**

```
int gid,uid;
uid=geteuid();
gid=getgid();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.